# Save text in fields in Activity

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have some of text blocks in activity, but when I change activity text in it dissapears.

How I can save text?

I know it is Shared preferences in Android. But how I can save text in activity by using it?

Code

```
private void Display (){
        LinearLayout display2 = FindViewById<LinearLayout> (Resource.Id.linearLayout12);        
        //LinearLayout display = FindViewById<LinearLayout> (Resource.Id.linearLayout13);           
        TextView productname = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.posttittle);
        TextView price = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.price);
        TextView weight = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.weight);


        productname.Text = Intent.GetStringExtra ("title");

        if (productname.Text == Intent.GetStringExtra ("title")) {
            display2.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        } 
        else {
            display2.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        }


        price.Text = Intent.GetStringExtra("price");
        weight.Text = Intent.GetStringExtra("weight");
        //display2.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        productname.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        price.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        weight.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    }
```

**My Axml**

```
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout12">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="147.6dp"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout13"
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:minWidth="25px"
                    android:minHeight="25px"
                    android:layout_width="276.2dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout24">
                    <TextView
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:layout_width="244.3dp"
                        android:layout_height="97.3dp"
                        android:id="@+id/posttittle"
                        android:layout_marginTop="22.4dp"
                        android:paddingTop="32dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16.8dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:minWidth="25px"
                    android:minHeight="25px"
                    android:layout_width="173.1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout25">
                    <TextView
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:layout_width="59.9dp"
                        android:layout_height="43.8dp"
                        android:id="@+id/weight"
                        android:layout_marginTop="54.6dp"
                        android:text="330u"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5.6dp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:layout_width="82.3dp"
                        android:layout_height="42.4dp"
                        android:id="@+id/price"
                        android:text="88.00uhy" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout23"
                android:background="#99999999" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tutorial :). Will show you how to use shared preferences so you can save the text.

[Shared Preferences](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)

Then when you have the value you wanted saved. You can call upon shared preferences and the value you have saved and set it in the text.

Comment: I can write text to value and call this value from all activities?

Comment: Yes :). A shared preference is basically a file created with values stored by you like a key value type. You then just call the value in your on create and store is as a field :). They are very handy! You could start looking into using the sqlite database too :)

Comment: Also a very handy tutorial in looking up! http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/android-sharedpreferences-example/

Comment: Also if you are looking a cross-device solution, Akavache is a good solution : https://github.com/akavache/Akavache

Answer (score 0):

If you want retain the text values between activities you can use `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` and save the values in the bundle as name-value pair.

To get values from the bundle you can use `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/151940/3090861) answer for more details.

`SharedPreferences` can be used to maintain the values even after the app is killed, `onSaveInstanceState` is suitable to maintain the states between activities.